# Can I display the payment amount in PayPal Express Checkout using Basic Client Integration?

Tags: paypal, braintree

I would like to integrate PayPal Express Checkout in a Single Page JavaScript application. The easiest way to do this seem to be

a) the Braintree v.zero SDK, and
b) PayPal's checkout.js wrapping the Express Checkout REST API

If I use the Braintree v.zero SDK, the PayPal popup will show the amount of money I want to charge the user, and I can also disable shipping, as my page delivers online services. The downside is that v.zero is limited to certain countries.

So I tried the checkout.js approach instead, using "Basic Client integration" as described here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/

It works, but in this case the payment amount won't be displayed in the popup window. Is there a hidden option to allow this?

I am also wondering if there is a way to suppress the shipping address information.

I could not find any documentation for checkout.js, so I am trying my luck here :-)

Comment: Can you try passing `commit: true` in the javascript options for checkout.js?

Comment: Yes, ```commit: true``` has been set. But it only affects the type of button displayed on the authorization popup. It won't show the amount, though.

At first sight, I thought this was a security feature since PP does not have a chance to check if the amount displayed in the popup would match the amount paid when executing the transaction. But even with the more advanced integrations (including a server roundtrip) such inconsistencies are possible.